# How to edit QQmlListProperty in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qobject

If we want to use a list of custom C++ objects in QML we can use `QQmlListProperty`

While registering it in QML we need to specify a function that QML will read the list with.

The documentation states that for fully functional list we need to use this function:

```
QQmlListProperty::QQmlListProperty(QObject *object, void *data, AppendFunction append,
                                   CountFunction count, AtFunction at, ClearFunction clear)
```

Here is example of how do I write it in C++:

*classwithlist.h*

```
#ifndef CLASSWITHLIST_H
#define CLASSWITHLIST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlListProperty>
#include "element.h"

class Element;

class ClassWithList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Element> elements  READ getElements  NOTIFY elementsChanged)


public:
    explicit ClassWithList(QObject *parent = 0);

    QQmlListProperty<Element> getElements();
    void appendElements(QQmlListProperty<Element> *list, Element *e);
    static int elementsCount(QQmlListProperty<Element> *list);
    static Element* elementsAt(QQmlListProperty<Element> *list, int i);
    static void elementsClear(QQmlListProperty<Element> *list);

signals:
    void elementsChanged(QQmlListProperty<Element>);

private:
    QList<Element *> m_elements;

};

#endif // CLASSWITHLIST_H
```

*classwithlist.cpp*

```
#include "classwithlist.h"

ClassWithList::ClassWithList(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QQmlListProperty<Element> ClassWithList::getElements()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<Element>(this, m_elements, &appendElements,&elementsCount,&elementsAt,&elementsClear);
}
void ClassWithList::appendElements(QQmlListProperty<Element> *list, Element *e)
{
    ClassWithList *cwl = qobject_cast<ClassWithList*>(list->object);
    if (cwl && e) {
        cwl->m_elements.append(e);
    }
}
int ClassWithList::elementsCount(QQmlListProperty<Element> *list)
{
    ClassWithList *cwl = qobject_cast<ClassWithList*>(list->object);
    if (cwl)
        return cwl->m_elements.count();
    return 0;
}
Element *ClassWithList::elementsAt(QQmlListProperty<Element> *list, int i)
{
    ClassWithList *cwl = qobject_cast<ClassWithList*>(list->object);
    if (cwl)
        return cwl->m_elements.at(i);
    return 0;
}
void ClassWithList::elementsClear(QQmlListProperty<Element> *list)
{
    ClassWithList *cwl = qobject_cast<ClassWithList*>(list->object);
    if (cwl) {
        cwl->m_elements.clear();
    }
}
```

And after exposing the class to QML I have following code in QML

```
ClassWithList {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(elements.length) // works
        console.log(elements[0])     // works

//        elements.push()      // does not work
//        elements.append()    // does not work
//        elements.clear()     // does not work
//        elements.at()        // does not work
    }
}
```

Can I use functions that will add items to the list or clear it? As seen above I can use functions `CountFunction` and `AtFunction` by using `.length` and brackets. Can I somehow use `ClearFunction` and `AppendFunction` too?

Maybe I cannot do this with `QQmlListProperty` and I should use `QAbstractListModel`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:** Due to changes in the list property interface, the answer below is no longer completly true. It is now possible to append objects by using `push` (from the documentation linked below):

> Values can be dynamically added to the list by using the push method, as if it were a JavaScript Array

Original answer below

---

You cannot append elements to or clear a `QQmlListProperty` directly in QML. To edit `QQmlListProperty` in QML, assign a new list to it.

According to QML `list` [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html):

> Any `QQmlListProperty` value passed into QML from C++ is automatically converted into a `list` value, and vice-versa.
>
> Note that objects cannot be individually added to or removed from the list once created; to modify the contents of a list, it must be reassigned to a new list.